# How to concatenate "by chromosome"-VCFs?

Tags: vcf, vcftools

I have a several VCFs which are VCF which only contain information by chromosome. That is, there's a chromosome 1 VCF (with only chr1), a chromosome 2 VCF (with only chr2), etc.

I checked to make sure that these VCFs were valid via `VCFtools`, i.e.

```
$ vcf-validator chr1.vcf
```

which works---these are valid VCFs I was given.

Now, I would like to combine these VCFs into one VCF.

I naïvely tried the following `cat` operation:

```
$ cat chr1.vcf chr2.vcf chr3.vcf ... chrX.vcf > total_chroms.vcf
```

This doesn't work properly though

```
$ vcf-validator total_chroms.vcf
The header tag 'contig' not present for CHROM=chr1. (Not required but highly recommended.)
Could not parse the line, wrong number of columns: [##fileformat=VCFv4.2\n]
 at /path/vcftools-0.1.14/perl/Vcf.pm line 172, <__ANONIO__> line 191016.
     Vcf::throw('Vcf4_2=HASH(0x1ae7208)', 'Could not parse the line, wrong number of columns: [##filefor...') called at  /path/vcftools-0.1.14/perl/Vcf.pm line 335
     Vcf::next_data_array('Vcf4_2=HASH(0x1ae7208)') called at  /path/vcftools-0.1.14/perl/Vcf.pm line 3457
     Vcf4_1::next_data_array('Vcf4_2=HASH(0x1ae7208)') called at  /path/vcftools-0.1.14/perl/Vcf.pm line 2574
     VcfReader::run_validation('Vcf4_2=HASH(0x1ae7208)') called at  /path/vcftools-0.1.14//bin/vcf-validator line 60
     main::do_validation('HASH(0x16ada68)') called at  /path/vcftools-0.1.14//bin/vcf-validator line 14
$
```

What tools are available to merge these VCF's together into a total VCF?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend [bcftools](https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html) concat.  You can't just `cat` them together because each file has a header section.  The bcftools command will handle all that for you.  Each vcf file must be sorted prior to calling `concat`

`bcftools concat -o total_chroms.vcf chr1.vcf chr2.vcf chr3.vcf ... chrX.vcf`

Comment: It's a bit odd. `vcf-validator chr1.vcf` shows no problems. I believe the output of `bcftools concat -o chroms12.vcf chr1.vcf chr2.vcf` shows an error: `FIXME: sequence name chr1 in chr1.vcf`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang the errors seem to indicate that you have `chr1` in the CHROM field for some rows, but no corresponding line in the header. Can you check if that is true in the `chr1.vcf` file? Maybe the validator somehow is missing this error?

Comment: @juod The VCF header looks correct to me. `#CHROM POS ID REF ALT QUAL FILTER INFO`

Comment: @juod "but no corresponding line in the header" Maybe I don't understand this. Besides the code pasted above, there is no other "chrom" information in the header

Comment: According to the VCF spec https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.1.pdf there should be header lines for each chromosome this is from the first example in the linked documents - `##contig=<ID=20,length=62435964,assembly=B36,md5=f126cdf8a6e0c7f379d618ff66beb2da,species="Homo sapiens",taxonomy=x>`

Comment: @Bioathlete I see. I think I understand now---this issue has been discussed before: https://github.com/samtools/bcftools/issues/326
I know that these VCFs are from hg38. Could I simply add the line `##contig=<ID=chr1,length=248956422>`, etc. to the VCFs in question? I would just take the chromosome lengths from hg38

Comment: @ShanZhengYang try that - it should work. I don't even think it's necessary to provide the length, but you could experiment and let us know.

Comment: @juod The above worked! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for the job is probably `bcftools` as [suggested](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/3306/298) by Bioathlete, but you can also do this manually. You just need to collect all header lines from all vcf files, remove any duplicates, and then print all the headers + the actual data into the new one:

```
grep '^##' chr*vcf | sort | uniq > all.vcf
grep -m1 '^#CHR' chr1.vcf >> all.vcf  ## Get the chr header line 
grep -v '^#' chr*vcf >> all.vcf
```

Comment: I appear to get a malformed VCF header with the above commands

Comment: @ShanZhengYang malformed how? Could you edit your question and show us an example of your files?

Comment: So, I see the above `grep` commands give the same behavior with all of my standard VCFs. I'll get something like this in `all.vcf`:
`chr10.vcf:##contig=<ID=chr10,length=133797422>
chr10.vcf:##fileDate=20121011
chr10.vcf:##fileformat=VCFv4.2
chr10.vcf:##reference=path/reference.fa
chr10.vcf:##source=foobar
chr11.vcf:##contig=<ID=chr10,length=133797422>
chr11.vcf:##fileDate=20121011
chr11.vcf:##fileformat=VCFv4.2
chr11.vcf:##reference=path/reference.fa
chr11.vcf:##source=foobar
....`

Answer (score 2):

use picard **GatherVcf**: http://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/command-line-overview.html#GatherVcfs

> Gathers multiple VCF files from a scatter operation into a single VCF file. Input files must be supplied in genomic order and must not have events at overlapping positions.

Comment: The error I get here is `Exception in thread "main" picard.PicardException: In order to index the resulting VCF input VCFs must contain ##contig lines.`. It is true, my "by chromosome"-VCFs do not contain a `##contig` line in the header...but I'm not sure that would matter

Comment: Edit above: Apparently this issue has been discussed before: github.com/samtools/bcftools/issues/326 
Question: how could I add these contig lines if I don't know this information?I know that these VCFs are from hg38. Could I simply add the line `##contig=<ID=chr1,length=248956422>`, etc. to the VCFs in question? I would just take the chromosome lengths from hg38

Comment: "but I'm not sure that would matter" it checks the order of the contigs using the dict. use UpdateVcfSequenceDictionary https://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/command-line-overview.html

Comment: "it checks the order of the contigs using the dict. use UpdateVcfSequenceDictionary". Ah, I understand now. Thanks for the help!